# Sending data to other activity using sharedpreferences android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i found a tutorial on the internet for saving and loading text from the same text fields in the                                                                               same activity. but i want to load some of the data (**Name** and **Age**) in the Text Views of another activity. how do i do that

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    TextView name;
    TextView email;// age
    TextView gender;//weight
    TextView height;
    public static final String mypreference = "mypref";
    public static final String Name = "nameKey";
    public static final String Email = "emailKey";
    public static final String Gender = "genderKey";
    public static final String Height = "heightKey";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        gender = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etGender);
        height = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etHeight);
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreference,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Name)) {
            name.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Name, ""));
        }
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Email)) {
            email.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Email, ""));
        }
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Gender)) {
            gender.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Gender, ""));
        }
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Height)) {
            height.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Height, ""));

        }

    }

    public void Save(View view) {
        String n = name.getText().toString();
        String e = email.getText().toString();
        String g = gender.getText().toString();
        String h = height.getText().toString();
        Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(Name, n);
        editor.putString(Email, e);
        editor.putString(Gender, g);
        editor.putString(Height, h);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void clear(View view) {
        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        gender = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etGender);
        height = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etHeight);
        name.setText("");
        email.setText("");
        gender.setText("");
        height.setText("");

    }

    public void Get(View view) {
        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        gender = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etGender);
        height = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etHeight);
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreference,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Name)) {
            name.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Name, ""));
        }
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Email)) {
            email.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Email, ""));
        }
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Gender)) {
            gender.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Gender, ""));
        }
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Height)) {
            height.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Height, ""));

        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for sending data for new activity
Declare both variable in main activity

```
public static final String TAG_NAME = "nameKey";
public static final String TAG_AGE = "emailKey";

Intent actt = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NewActivity.class);
actt.putExtra(TAG_AGE,age.getText().toString());
actt.putExtra(TAG_NAME,name.getText().toString());
startActivity(actt);
```

In NewActivity to receive in oncreate method

```
public class NewActivity extends Activity {

    TextView name;
    TextView age;         

    public static final String TAG_NAME = "nameKey";
    public static final String TAG_AGE = "emailKey";      

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        age = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.age);

        String Name=getIntent().getStringExtra(TAG_NAME);
        String Age=getIntent().getStringExtra(TAG_AGE);

        name.setText(Name);
        age.setText(Age);
    }
}
```

Method 2 using sharedpreferances

```
public class NewActivity extends Activity {
   public static final String mypreference = "mypref";
       TextView name;
       TextView age;            

       public static final String TAG_NAME = "nameKey";
       public static final String TAG_AGE = "emailKey";


       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
           age = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.age);
           sharedpreferences=getSharedPreferences(mypreference,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
           String Name=sharedpreferences.getString(TAG_NAME,"");
           String Age=sharedpreferences.getString(TAG_AGE,"");

           name.setText(Name);
           age.setText(Age);
        }
}
```

Comment: just use yourtextviewName.setText(Name); for further help plz add your second activity code where you want to load data

Comment: check edited i dont know where you maintaining your age according to that change in age

Comment: one thing from where you calling second activity plz share all code so we can help you better

Comment: @Toxic check edited answer may now you will get clear idea

Comment: check updated answer as suggestion please go through basic intent and activities

Comment: so what is your requirement now or problem

Comment: @Toxic if this answer helped you you can accept the answer

Comment: so put the code where you want to call second activity
by calling 
Intent actt = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NewActivity.class);
actt.putExtra(TAG_AGE,age.getText().toString(););
actt.putExtra(TAG_NAME,name.getText().toString());
startActivity(actt);

Comment: you are not getting it. if i put this code in the save button, it would send the data but also launch the second activity on its own (which i dont want) i just want it to send the data so i can load it in the second activity later

Comment: it will send only data when you startnewactivity using this intent if you want data without any internal communication you can use shared preferences in new activity which you implemented in current activity
@Toxic check updated answer

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two ways to do that.
1. Passing data by intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(TAG_AGE, <insert age here>);
intent.putExtra(TAG_NAME, <insert name here>);
startActivity(intent);
```

and load the data in the onCreate method of OtherActivity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String age = intent.getStringExtra(TAG_AGE);
String name = intent.getStringExtra(TAG_NAME);
ageTextView.setText(age);
nameTextView.setText(name);
```

2. Fetching data by sharedpreference
Since you have save your data in the MainActivity using the sharedpreference which is shared by the whole application, you can fetch the data in the onCreate method of OtherActivity using the method below:

```
 sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreference,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 nameTextView.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Name, ""));
 ageTextView.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Age, ""));
```

It's the same way you used in the MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data to another activity in the `Intent` used to start the activity.

```
Intent newActivity = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,OtherActivity.class);
newActivity.putExtra(TAG_ADDRESS,<insert address here>);
newActivity.putExtra(TAG_NAME,<insert name here>);
startActivity(newActivity);
```

In the other activity, you can retrieve the `Intent` by calling `getIntent()` and then `getStringExtra()` to get the name and address.